# Are these definitions of a differential form equivalent?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, tangent-bundle

The definition from my notes says that a differential $k$-form is a section of $\bigwedge^k T^*X \rightarrow X$, so $\omega \in \Omega^k(X)$ would be a map $\omega : X \rightarrow \bigwedge^k T^*X$ satisfying the condition for a section.

John Lee's text defines a $k$-form as a section of $\coprod_{p \in X} \bigwedge^k (T_pX) \rightarrow X$. Are these two definitions equivalent? I know that the cotangent bundle $T^*X$ is defined as $$T^*X = \{ (p, \alpha) \mid p \in X, \alpha \in T_p^*X \}$$ so that $\alpha$ is a map $\alpha : T_pX \rightarrow \mathbb R$ (the tangent space in this case is a real vector space). I know that we can also write the cotangent bundle as $T^*X = \coprod_{p \in X} T^*_pX$. But then how are the above two definitions equivalent? Substituting what I just wrote for the cotangent bundle into $\bigwedge^k T^*X$ from the first definition gives $\bigwedge^k \coprod_{p \in X} T^*_pX = \coprod_{p \in X} \bigwedge^k T^*_pX$ (I have assumed that the disjoint union and exterior product commute here) whereas we should have $T_pX$ in this equation rather than $T^*_pX$ according to the second definition. Could anyone please shed some light on where I am going wrong here?

On a related note, I would like to ask what a differential form evaluated at a point (denote it $\omega(p) =: \omega_p$) takes as its argument? I am an unsure of this because I am unsure of the above discussion. I think it would either take a coefficient times a wedge of things in $T_pX$ or $T_p^*X$, depending on where I've gone wrong above.

**Edit**: I suppose that $T_pX \cong T_p^*X$ since in general a (finite dimensional, which we have here) vector space is isomorphic to its dual, but I'm still not sure if this solves my questions, i.e. what should I be taking as the arguments for $\omega_p$, and can what I asked really be resolved as simply as writing the standard isomorphism between a vector space and its dual?

Any help is much appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: It would help if you gave your definition for the vector bundle $\Lambda^k(T^*M)$?  Typically given a vector space $V$, we have the dual space $V^*$, and the space of covectors $\Lambda^kV$, which are our alternation tensors $\omega:V^k\to\mathbb{R}$.  That is, $\omega$ takes in $k$-vectors $v_1,...,v_k\in V$ and gives a real number.  I have a feeling this is just different notation, and not different definitions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, as discussed in Jack Lee's answer, I was indeed going wrong with the notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a question of notation. You didn't say which of my books you're looking at, but I gather it's either *Riemannian Manifolds* or the first edition of *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. I originally learned most of my differential geometry from [Spivak](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0914098705), who uses the notations $\mathcal T^k(V)$ and $\Omega^k(V)$ for the spaces of covariant $k$-tensors and alternating $k$-tensors on a vector space $V$, and correspondingly $\mathcal T^k(TX)$ and $\Omega^k(TX)$ for the bundles of $k$-tensors and $k$-forms on a manifold. When I wrote those books, I decided to change the notations a bit, to $T^k(V)$ and $\Lambda^k(V)$, but I kept Spivak's convention of using the notation $V$ to reflect the fact that covariant tensors are functions on $V$.

After those books were published, I realized that Spivak was an outlier in this notation, and almost everyone else in the world uses something like $T^k(V^*)$ and $\Lambda^k(V^*)$ for the spaces of covariant $k$-tensors and alternating $k$-tensors on $V$, with analogous notations for tensors and forms on a manifold. (The reason for this is that $T^k(V)$ is naturally isomorphic to $V^*\otimes \cdots \otimes V^*$, the $k$-th tensor product of $V^*$ with itself.) So in the second edition of *ISM* (and the second edition of *Riemannian Manifolds*, which should appear sometime in January or February), I've switched to the more common notations.

The upshot is that the definition of $\Lambda^k(T_pX)$ in my older books is exactly the same as the definition of $\Lambda^k(T_p^*X)$ in my newer ones and in your notes: It's the space of real-valued alternating multilinear functions on $T_pX$.

While it's true that $T_pX$ and $T_p^*X$ are isomorphic vector spaces (simply because they have the same dimension), there is no "standard isomorphism" between them. So it definitely makes a difference that we think of differential forms as multilinear functions on the *tangent space*, not on its dual.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer - I understand where I was going wrong now. The book I have is indeed the first edition of *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. Let me take this opportunity to say that it’s a great book which I've found very useful – thank you for writing it!

Comment: @mathphys — you’re welcome! If you get a chance, take a look at the 2nd edition — it’s much better!